# Show message when print done odoo

Tags: odoo-8, openerp-8, qweb

I am facing a problem while printing from wizard, all is good that the report is printed but it does not give any popup saying that report is printed only the wizard is closed. 
I want to show a popup message when the printing process is done. so i thought to have a warning but then the wizard does not closes by itself.

My code is as below:

```
try:
        return self.env['report'].print_report(active_ids,report_name)
    finally:
        raise except_orm(('Information!'), ('Sent to Printer ') + str(printer.system_name))
```

it does popup the information but the original wizard does not closes by itself.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

When you print report at that time odoo will return report for print in URL, that's why Wizard will not close.

You can see odoo default report, system will print report but wizard will  not close automatically.

[image]

Comment: Hi Dipesh, but when i remove the finally and only do try, it closes the wizard. is there a way to redirect to same page with message.